# Password with no maximum limit. How to handle it server-side?

Tags: php, passwords, limit, denial-of-service

I have a password field in my form that has no maximum length limit.

The password will be hashed into the database with the PHPass framework.

I've read some places that big data entries through fields like that with no maximum limit can DoS a site.

So my question is:

- **How should I handle big password data entries on the server-side (with PHP)?**

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

**Either**

Add a length limit that is high but not dangerously high - e.g. 128 chars is more than most real people will ever use **but** add an appeals process, i.e. a link that people can click to request specific exceptions from a human being,

**OR**

Have a javascript element compute the hash client side and only submit the hash - this is better for security anyway as the password never leaves the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to protect yourself from a DoS, you would have to use:
post-max-size - http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

This allows you to control how much POST data will be accepted by the PHP server, be mindful as this also controls how large files can be if your form is uploading files.

Answer (score 0):

An attacker can always send big data to your server, whether this is a password field or another field, it is not possible to prevent this client side with HTML or JavaScript. What you can do is to stop working on server side when huge input was sent, though this limit should be really high.

Keep in mind that for iterated hash functions like BCrypt, only the first calculation has more data to work with, other iterations work with the previous hash. In my opinion there is no reason to limit a password to less than 1KB.